# Angular 2 Scroll while hovering over an element

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I'm creating an Angular 2 app where I need to scroll horizontally when hovering over 2 different divs. Currently I have

```
(mouseenter)
```

and `(mouseleave)`
events that trigger functions to make the div scroll. How can I scroll the div once the mouse has entered the div, but stop scrolling once the mouse has exited the div?

Comment: How did you structure the code? The 2 div to hover and the big div to scroll is located inside on component only?

Comment: You can do something like this: `<div (mouseenter)="scrollRight=true;scrollLeft=false" (mouseleave)="scrollRight=false">Right</div>` `<div (mouseenter)="scrollRight=false;scrollLeft=true" (mouseleave)="scrollLeft=false">Left</div>`

and in your constructor: `window.setInterval(() => {this.scrollRight && window.scrollBy(1,0); this.scrollLeft && window.scrollBy(-1, 0); }, 100)`

Comment: Works great, i'm sure theres a more efficient way but i'll leave that for later. I'm trying to find how I can implement easing into this, any ideas?

Comment: Two obs: 1.-NOT use window, just setInterVal(), 2.-use a variable and clearInterval to stop the scroll